# tokenize text field for suggestions search

Tags: elasticsearch

In my current index, I have a text field. I want to use separate words from this field as suggestions.
the example:

```
{text: "af bf aff bff"},
{text: "afff bfff "}
```

so for "af" term request, I should have "af, aff, afff" suggestions.

I am looking at the elastic search-suggesters functionality, but it is still not clear how I can achieve desirable behaver. 
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters.html

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Term Suggeste](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters-term.html)r, it uses an analyzer that will split your text into tokens.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, should be ok or pretty close. Please not you have to reindex your documents (try in a new index so)

PUT your_index

```
{
    {
      "settings": {
        "analysis": {
          "analyzer": {
            "my_sugester_analyzer": {
              "tokenizer": "my_tokenizer_sugester"
            }
          },
          "tokenizer": {
            "my_tokenizer_sugester": {
              "type": "ngram",
              "min_gram": 1,
              "max_gram": 20,
              "token_chars": [
                "lowercase",
                "name_ngrams",
                "standard"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
   "mappings": {
    "_doc": {
      "properties": {
        "your_text": {
          "type": "text",
          "analyzer": "my_sugester_analyzer",
          "search_analyzer": "my_sugester_analyzer"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @JeBigCat Thank you for pointed to me a direction. I tried different combinations of params, but it does not work. I cannot post code in a comment so this is a link https://gist.github.com/YaroslavTir/b6b754c7aff527a382d25b2f551f1cb9